# Strong Sobolev inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Take $B(0,1)$ the ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the normalized Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ such that $\int_{B(0,1)} d \lambda=1.$

Now, I want to show, or give a counterexample that this is false, that for all $f \in H^1_0(B(0,1))$ we have
for fixed constants $a,b>0$ and any(!) $p \in (2,\infty)$
\begin{equation}
||f||_p^2 \le a \left(\int_{B(0,1)}| \nabla f|^2 d\lambda \right) + b ||f||_2^2.
\end{equation}

Does anybody know how to do this? The normal Sobolev inequality is apparently too weak to show this, as this holds for any $p$ and fixed $a,b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such a $a, b$ is found for a $f\in W^{1,2}_0(B)$, then 
$$\|f\|_p <C$$

for all $p >2$. In particular, this shows $\|f\|_\infty \le C$ as [$\|f\|_p \to \|f\|_\infty$ as $p\to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm).

In particular, $f\in L^\infty$. Thus one cannot find such an $a, b$ for even a fixed unbounded $f\in W^{1,2}_0(B)$. In particular, pick $\phi$ be a smooth function supported in $B_{3/4}(0)$ and is $1$ on $B_{1/2}(0)$. Then

$$f(x) = -\phi(x) \log\left(\log \left(1 +\frac 1{|x|}\right)\right)$$

is such an example.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Sobolev embedding theorem?

Given your domain is a ball, $W_0^{1,2}(B) = H_0^{1}(B)$. 
In this case $W^{1,p}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $p=n=2$, we have the continuous embedding
$$W^{1,2}_0(B) \hookrightarrow L^q(B) \text{ for all } q\in [1,+\infty),$$
that is 
$$\|f\|_q \leq C \bigg(\int_B |f|^2 dx +\int_B|\nabla f|^2 dx \bigg)^{1/2}.$$
(This is w.r.t. standard Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: sorry, could you state the embedding theorem you are using? This would help me quite a lot, because I feel there are 1000 different Sobolev embedding theorems in the internet.

Comment: @user167575 see the first part of the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/sobolev-embedding-case-p-n

Comment: but $C$ is not the same constant for all $q$ right?

Comment: @user167575 You are right, $C$ depends on $q$. I will take a look again.